# Implementing multiple storm topologies

Tags: apache-storm

I am working on a storm topology where I need to build multiple topologies for different client locations.

I have a Kafka server producing data that needs to reach remote client machine(after some transformation in the bolts). There are about 1000 of those clients.
when there is new data produced in the Kafka, the clients need to get that data in few minutes.
There is some transformation that needs to happen (which can be handled by the bolts) and the data is sent to the remote client via websocket.

e.g: Kafka server -> Kafka spout -> Bolt1 -> bolt2 -> bolt3 -> websocket (on a client machine)
I have 1000 client machines.

I am hoping that this topology can be dynamically created per client. When the client is ready, can they initiate this topology and start reading the data?
or can these topologies (1000 of them) be created on the storm and ready to send the data?

Is this architecture possible with Storm?
How efficient is this?
Is the Storm setup manageable?

thanks for your response.

Comment: does each client has is own kafka topic, or the kafka topic is the same for all of them?

Comment: Is the processing you are doing on each tuple the same or client specific?

Comment: Each topic is applicable to multiple client locations. The way I am thinking is that the message has to be opened by one of the bolts(bolt1), look at the location information and then connect to the appropriate websocket location to send the data.

Comment: @Doomy, the processing on each tuple is the same. The data format is the same for every client, but the actual daya may not be applicable to every client.

Comment: my topology might look like this: Kafka spout (1000 instances)->bolt1 (100 instances) -> bolt2 (100 instances) -> bolt3 (1000 each connecting to 1000 sockets ) -> websocket (1000 different remote servers)

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a topology per client would not be the standard way of handling your problem. Since the data processing needs of each client is identical, the more conventional approach would be to have a single topology that reads from an input queue (typically Kafka), performs the processing, and then reports back to the clients.

You specifically call out dynamically creating a topology per client. That certainly is possible, but I don't think its necessary given what I understand about what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks!would you be able to draw a picture of the topology. I wanted to post one pic of what I was thinking, but I don't have enough reputation to add one. so sorry. If you could post what you are thinking, that would be great!

Comment: You've already laid out the DAG of the topology, yes? Kafka-spout -> bolt1 -> bolt2 -> bolt3 -> websocket.  I'm not sure what you are asking for here.